# Allure reporter - Scenario Outline not recognised as separate scenarios

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs, allure

I am using Webdriverio 4.2, cucumber js 1.3.3 with Allure reporter. I get the JSON report generated correctly but when I generate the Allure report using allure-commandline 2.5, it is squashing the scenarios from Scenario Outline together, looks like when it sees same Scenario Name in JSON file, it just combines them all together and report them as same scenario. We heavily use Scenario Outlines in out test framework due to different flavours of the application we test and this help us test them all in same run.

Has anyone encountered something like this before, since there are many node modules here its very difficult to tell which might be causing the issue.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 0):

I've also run in to this issue. Seems like a bug in the wdio allure-reporter/cucumber service. There is [a PR open](https://github.com/webdriverio/wdio-cucumber-framework/pull/126) to fix it, although it seems to be stalled a little at the moment.

Comment: I am facing the same issue  in "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^6.1.23" Any inputs please?